# Grant unique permission on an excel file in shared document but some permission grayed out

Tags: document-library, permissions

i've an excel workbook at shared libray, and i want to grant the permission:

- **anonymous can can edit and view** but when i go to 
  shared Documents -> tick the checkbox of the excel file->Library Tools->Library->Library Permissions->click anonymous access, Add Items/Edit Items/Delete Items are all grayed out
- **system account have Full control** but there is a tick on "Limited Access" and grayed out when i go shared Documents -> onmouseover the excel file->right click manage permission->tick system account->edit user Permissions

How can i make about grayed checkout to normal?

Answer (score 0):

For your first point:

You'd check the permissions the *Anonymous Access* grants.

> ## WITH ANONYMOUS ACCESS TO:
>
> ### 1. Entire web site
>
> ANONYMOUS USERS CAN:
>
> - Browse your entire site.
> - Read any lists, libraries, or folder within a list or library that inherits its permissions from the site, and open and read any list items or documents in those lists and libraries.
>
> ANONYMOUS USERS CANNOT:
>
> - Change the content.
>
> ### 2. **Lists and libraries**
>
> ANONYMOUS USERS CAN:
>
> - Read lists and libraries on which the View Items permission has been granted to anonymous users.
>
> ANONYMOUS USERS CANNOT:
>
> - Browse the site.
> - Change the content.

source: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/grant-permissions-to-anonymous-users-HA101805390.aspx

This means they are intended to not have any permissions to Edit/Add/Delete items.

For your second point:

I'd check first the inheriting of the permissions, whether it has been broken at some level once navigating up to the Excel file. I suppose the user doesn't even actually have the permissions you are assuming.

Read more about the SharePoint's System Account [here](http://www.sharepoint-insight.com/2010/09/05/what-is-sharepointsystem-account-2/) and [here](http://vogtland.ws/markedwardvogt/?p=1016).